# Is this a valid formulation of three dimensional Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I've learned 1D quantum mechanics so far. I was thinking of generalising the ideas into three dimensions. This is what seems most natural to me:

The wave-function is no longer a linear vector, but a three dimensional matrix. The wave function matrix should satisfy in the position basis:

$$\iiint|\psi (x,y,z)|^2 dx dy dz=1$$

The wave function can be converted to the momentum basis using a Fourier transform. The Fourier transform is no longer just a 2D infinite matrix. I think it should now be a 6 dimensional infinite matrix. My reasoning is: A three dimensional finite square matrix has $n^3$ elements. The fourier transform assigns to each of these elements, a three dimensional matrix with $n^3$ elements. So the total number of elements in the Fourier transform matrix is : $n^3\cdot n^3=n^6$. This implies six dimensions.

The Fourier transform should be:

$$\psi (p_x,p_y,p_z)=h^{-3/2}\iiint\psi(x,y,z) e^{i\left(\frac{2\pi x p_x}{h}+\frac{2\pi y p_y}{h}+\frac{2\pi z p_z}{h}\right)}dx dy dz$$

Similar to the Fourier transform, the Hamiltonian should be another 6 dimensional infinite matrix. The look of Schrodinger's equation seems to remain unchanged, as in it can still be written as:

$$i\frac{h}{2\pi}\frac{d}{dt} |\psi \rangle=H|\psi \rangle$$

But the wave function and the hamiltonian should respectively be interpreted as 3 dimensional and 6 dimensional matrices.

Is this the correct generalisation to three dimensions?

Comment: A vector is already a matrix, so what do you mean by the wavefunction is now a 3D matrix? What happens in the time dependent case? What is wrong with the current formulation of QM in 3D space?

Comment: @Triatticus I haven't studied the current formulation yet. I was expecting it to be this exact thing. By a 3D matrix, I mean a matrix with 3 dimensions, looking like a cube. These 3D matrices form a vector space. Since $\psi (x,y,z)$ has 3 variables, a 3D matrix seems to be the natural way to model it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "$6$-dimensional infinite matrix"?

Comment: @J.G. A six dimensional infinite cube. The vectors we're trying to Fourier transform are three dimensional matrices. So the Fourier transform has 6 dimensions.

Comment: @EggMan Oh, do you mean a rank-$6$ tensor on a vector of infinite dimension (if so, presumably $\aleph_0$ or $\beth_1$, but which)?

Comment: @J.G. No, I meant an infinite dimensional vector space (as in, the number of basis vectors is infinite). The elements of this vectors space are 3D infinite matrices $\psi (x,y,z)$. The "dimension" term is overloaded.

Comment: Then you'll have to explain what each element of the matrix of the wavefunction even means, for example what are the off diagonal terms, what do the indices mean when one says something like $\Psi_{12}$ and is this matrix symmetric (and how would you know for that matter)?

Comment: @Triatticus $\psi _{xyz}$ is the probability density at the point $(x,y,z)$. I'm only visualising $\psi (x,y,z)$ as a cubic matrix because it has three inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "wrong" *per se*, in the sense that you are going to get to the right expressions, but referring to the wavefunction as a matrix is not really the right way to think about it. Calling the wavefunction a matrix suggests that it has become an operator, when it is still just a vector in Hilbert space. The fact that you can split up the "index" of the vector into 3 parts does not really change the fact that you only have one index.

To give a concrete example of what I mean, if I have a matrix $M_{ij}$ I can multiply it by a vector $v_i$ to get a new vector, say $u_i$
$$
u_i = \sum_j M_{ij}v_j
$$
However if you were to multiply your "matrix" wavefunction, $\psi(x,y,z)$ by a "vector" function $f(x)$
$$
\int dz\; \psi(x,y,z)f(z)
$$
then, as far a quantum mechanics is concerned, you have done something really weird. You should always be getting integrals over all three spatial dimensions, for example in the Fourier transform you have
$$
\tilde{\psi}(p_x,p_y,p_z) = \int dx dy dz\; e^{\imath(p_x x + p_y y + p_z z)} \psi(x,y,z)
$$
That is you don't really have 3 indices, you have 1 vector valued index. In the same way the Hamiltonian (and all other operators) continue to correspond to matrices.

Comment: I don't agree. Matrices are a way to represent operators. That doesn't mean that every matrix must be interpreted as an operator. Matrices can represent other things too, like the wave-function here. And matrices are still vectors, as they satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: Yes, but like I said in the first line, it is not a question of things being right or wrong, it is a question of them being the natural way to think about the problem. Thinking about the wavefunction as a matrix (but not an operator) is just adding in some extra booking keeping that obscures the big picture and offers extra room for mistakes to creep in, whilst not adding any meaningful insight.

Comment: I just found it nice to visualise.